# call from ec2 instance to 169.254.169.254 for security credentials returns invalid credentials

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, authentication, credentials

So in theory, if a person needs valid credentials for an Amazon server, instead of hardcoding in their access key/password, one can call out to 169.254.169.254 for credentials to access certain resources like so:

```
   js = ''
   open('http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/<role>') { |f|
       f.each_line {|line| js += line}
   }
   credentials = JSON.load(js)

   ndnode[:s3_access_key_id] = credentials['AccessKeyId']
   ndnode[:s3_secret_access_key] = credentials['SecretAccessKey']
```

and then using the access stuff here:

```
   conn = AWS::EC2::Base.new(:access_key_id => ndnode[:s3_access_key_id],
       :secret_access_key => ndnode[:s3_secret_access_key])
   # THIS ALWAYS FAILS
   result = conn.describe_instances(:instance_id => instance_id)
```

I dislike the idea of hardcoding my access key and password into the source, and I'd like a workaround.

1) Am I and my boss correct that this is a way to do that workaround?
2) If yes to 1, what is the correct way of doing it?  If no to 1, is there a way to avoid checking credentials into the source (either here or in a config file) and what is it?
3) In response to @Edwin's response, where in the AWS gem API do I put the security token?  Boto has been reported to let me connect with the credentials that I'm given, which means forking off a process, and setting some environment variables, so that Ruby can use the Boto connection's asking for information.

Comment: I don't see a session_token anywhere.  You need to use a token with the temporary credentials provided by the instance profile.  Are you using the node.js API?

Comment: I don't think so.  I inherited some ancient Ruby Chef scripts, so I'm learning Chef, Ruby, and AWS at the same time.  I'll try it out.  Thanks.

Comment: After trying it, there's no place in the connection constructor for a token. [link](http://rdoc.info/github/grempe/amazon-ec2/AWS/Base#initialize-instance_method).  There's a token coming down with the credentials though, so that has to be it.  Now to figure out where the 'AWS' rubygem wants me to put the token.  Seriously, thanks.

Comment: Is that what ruby looks like :)  Obviously, I can't help you with the ruby, but for the .Net AWS SDK, you use parameterless constructors to indicate that you want to use the Instance Profile Credentials.  Make sure you're using a recent version of the SDK.  Here's a webpage on how to use profile credentials http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsRuby/latest/DeveloperGuide/ruby-dg-roles.html

Comment: That did it.  Make it an answer and I'll mark it correct.  Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many of the AWS SDKs have support for IAM Roles in EC2 Profiles built in. With .Net, you use a parameterless constructor to use them.  Make sure you're using a recent version of the SDK.

Here's [Amazon's page on how to use the Ruby SDK with IAM Roles](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsRuby/latest/DeveloperGuide/ruby-dg-roles.html).